# Copy one table to another with different colum count

Tags: php, mysql

As i am far from an expert in php this got me stunned and i can't seem to make a script for it.

Lets see if i can explain this as clearly as possible.

Lets say i have table1 and table2

`Table1 = (teamid, name, round1pos, round1score, round2pos, round2score)`

Table2 = (id, tournamentid, teamid, name, round1pos, round1score, round2pos, round2score...till round10pos/round10score)

When copied from table1 to table 2 i want to add 2 fields in front of it. (id and tournamentid)

The problem i am facing is that Table1 has a different amount of roundxpos/roundxscore each time.

Basically what i want to do is once a tournament is over i want to delete the table. but copy the data inside it to another table to archive the results. but each tournament can have a different size of rounds.

I hope someone can understand what i am trying to achieve +_+.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad table design. Can you change it?

Comment: You can try normalize your database so you don't have to use a roundX anything, but use another associated table (with tournamentID as foreign key).Also, I've never seen the need to "delete" a table (which can itself serve as archive anyway), especially because the database user might not have the permission to do that command (only INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE). Or did you mean "delete rows"?

Comment: The table design is pretty bad and a whole rewrite of the script will come in around 6 months. normally you could delete a tournament once it ended and that would delete the table that holds those scores. but i want to keep the data so people can still refer back to it thus trying to archive it. Wouldn't to many tables slow up the database? else i would just leave it like it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a third table, remove the roundX columns from your existing tables and reference them with their IDs.

```
rounds: team_id, tournament_id, no, pos, score
```

Comment: that would indeed be the better solution, however seeing the script is kinda terry bad and a rewrite is comming in 6 months i was looking for a temp solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your tables but in the meantime....
I'm assuming the main problem is handling the variable number of roundxpos and roundxscore columns in the code.

Hope this helps:

- Get the results of this query: SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table1 WHERE Field LIKE 'round%pos'
- Get the results of this query: SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table1 WHERE Field LIKE 'round%score'
- Create the table2 inserts by looping through field names

  ```
  //example, assuming results are fetched into an associative array
  $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (tournamentid, teamid, name)";
  foreach($roundpos_fields as $f){  $query .= "," . $f['Field'];  }
  foreach($roundscore_fields as $f){  $query .= "," . $f['Field'];  }
  $query .= "( SELECT $tournamentid, '' teamid, name"; 
  foreach($roundpos_fields as $f){  $query .= "," . $f['Field'];  }
  foreach($roundscore_fields as $f){  $query .= "," . $f['Field'];  }        
  $query .= ")";
  ```